# Why can't I return $.ajax result but can return $http.post result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, google-chrome

I have 2 return statements:

```
return $http.post({ 
    url: CHEAPWATCHER.config.domain + 'api/Authenticate',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    data: data
});

return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: CHEAPWATCHER.config.domain + 'api/Authenticate',
    data: data
}).done(function (result) {
    console.log('logged successfuly');
}).fail(function (result) {
    console.log('loging failed');
});
```

and my background.js function that uses API methods:

```
// REGISTER API COMMAND LISTENER
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (request, portInfo) {
        // Globally accessible function to execure API calls
        CHEAPWATCHER.executeApiCall = function (request, senderId) {
            var originalRequestMethod = request.method;
            //Dinamically call API method
            CHEAPWATCHER.api[request.method](request, senderId).then(function (response) {
                port.postMessage(response);
            }, function (error) {
                port.postMessage(error);
            });
        };
        CHEAPWATCHER.executeApiCall(request, request.sender);
    });
});
```

So ofcourse when I'm running my chrome extension I comment one of them, but the point is that both of them return the same object type jqXHR and if I'm using $http.post it gives me these errors:

> Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null

and

> POST chrome-extension://cmakfpdagfeiefcmmpmhjrtyhonmgnbi/background/[object%20Object] net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

and when I'm using $.ajax it works, I get the token I needed but it gives me this error:

> Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null

and after that my extension can't continue working. Yesterday I asked why $.ajax gives me that error and I got answer because I can't return jqXHR type, but if I'm using

```
return $http.post(CHEAPWATCHER.config.domain + 'api/Authenticate', data);
```

everything is fine just post method wants that I give him grant_type=password and Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded so that's why I used $http.post([settings]) structure.

Can someone please explain me how they both work and why I'm getting these errors? Maybe I'm using post method incorrectly or I need to declare something more that I don't know?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry forgot to mention that I'm using Angular. So $http service is a core Angular service that facilitates communication with the remote HTTP servers via the browser's XMLHttpRequest object or via JSONP.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @AhsanAyaz jQuery 2.2.1 version

Comment: Where do these response (promises) get returned to?  "Cannot read property 'error' of null" suggests that, at some point, someObject.error is being referenced.

Comment: Also "chrome-extension://cmakfpdagfeiefcmmpmhjrtyhonmgnbi/background/[object%20Object] " seems highly suspect, because it looks like an object is trying to added to a string (given the [object Object] serialization) -- though that's less related to the issue your are having.

Comment: @TheMadDeveloper response goes to background.js where there is method that dinamically calls API methods. It has angular function .then()

Comment: Can you post that code of background.js please? @NikasŽalias

Comment: Edited my question! @AhsanAyaz

Comment: @NikasŽalias since we posted our comment in the same time i'm posting it again to be sure you don't miss it : angular does only transform object to json or string. If you want it to be urlencoded you have to do it yourself.

Comment: I'd just like to make a point, that you should be using either angular OR jquery. not both.

Comment: Got it! I'll try to change it myself @Walfrat

Comment: @Hazonko : $.Ajax is probably more familair for some developers. $http fits for json datas. Other things imply a bit of "do it yourself" but of course it almost always doable. However if you use $.Ajax you will be outside of angular loop and you have to remeber using $scope.$apply every time. This is why it's better to try to use only $http mainly.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using [$http.post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) correctly. This method take 3 parameters not one object like this :

```
return $http.post(
   CHEAPWATCHER.config.domain + 'api/Authenticate',
   transformDataToUrlEncoded(data),
   {contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
});
```

As you can see i put a transformDataToUrlEncoded. Because angular only serialize in JSON he doesn't antively transform javascript object to urlencoded.

---

From old answer that is out of subject

$http.post return a promise on which you can use the .then. 
Angular promise are chanable, meaning you can do .then().then().then() again and again to have multiple layer of processing the result. Of course you don't need that often. I would say almost never than 2 level :

1. Processing the result from server and format data in a service layer
2. Using the result in a controller layer

I don't really know about JQuery but i guess that's it's not chainable as angular.

You probably can do

```
.done().fail()
```

Because .done return on object on which you can perform a .fail() but not

```
.done().done().
```

Because the object returned by .done doesn't have a .done() method.

Finally the .fail() is the terminate point : it return nothing so you return null value.

---

Comment: In http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-settings says that there are format of $http.post that looks like this: jQuery.post( [settings ] ) and settings are plainObject so You can use 1 plainObject parameter @Walfrat

Comment: jQuery promises are chainable as well.  As I understand from @NikasŽalias question, the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null" happens for both the angular and jQuery implementation.  I suspect this is happening down the line, and it might help to figure out how far the code gets before throwing this error.

Comment: Also, good catch on the $http.post usage issue @Walfrat--that's likely what is causing the weird post url with [object Object] in the angular version

Comment: So as @Walfrat mentioned I changed my $http.post syntax to his suggested one. and it threw an error that grant_type is not supported so my data was sent as JSON and not as x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Yes angular does not handle application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 content-type he has to transform the object himself

Comment: Less familiar with AngularJS, but you might have to send headers as part of a headers hash.  You might try: return $http.post(
   CHEAPWATCHER.config.domain + 'api/Authenticate',
   transformDataToUrlEncoded(data),
   {headers: {contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;', charset:"UTF-8"}
});

Answer (score 0):

So after lots of google'ing and thinking I came to solution that maybe some day it may help to someone. Insted of $html.post() and $.ajax() method I transformed my data to x-www-form-urlencoded as @Walfrat and @TheMadDeveloper suggested so my code that now works perfectly loks like this:

```
return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: CHEAPWATCHER.config.domain + 'api/Authenticate',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    transformRequest: function (obj) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            return str.join("&");
        },
        data: data
    }).success(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
});
```

Thank you all for help!!!